# I get a warning message saying "Do not mutate state directly."

Tags: reactjs

My code is perfectly working but I keep getting this warning message "Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()". I tried to use the setState for the currentNumber and inputs as follows:

```
this.setState({currentNumber: this.state.currentNumber.toString() + numberbtn.toString()})
this.setState({inputs: this.state.currentNumber})
```

but it shows the output on the second click rather than the first click.
Down below is the full code that is working for me but shows the warning message.

```
import React from 'react'
import DisplayComponent from './components/DisplayComponent'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        inputs: '',
        result: '',
        currentNumber: '',
      }
  }

  inputNumber = numberbtn => {
    this.state.currentNumber = this.state.currentNumber.toString() + numberbtn.toString()
    this.state.inputs = this.state.currentNumber 
    this.setState({result: this.state.inputs})
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className = "container">
              <div className = "display">
                  <DisplayComponent result={this.state.result}/>
              </div>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(1)}>1</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(2)}>2</button>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `currentNumber`, `inputs` and `result`? It looks like they all store the same value. Why?

Comment: I am trying to build a calculator. so when the number button is clicked, the number is stored in the current number and the current number will pass the value to inputs. when you click an operator, the previous number will have the value of the current number, and current number will be empty. Inputs will store the numbers and operator. The result will get the value of the inputs and display it on the screen. I just posted part of the code here. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are updating the state directly, like `this.state.currentNumber = ...`.
I would suggest to use some variables.

```
inputNumber = numberbtn => {
    let currentNumber = this.state.currentNumber.toString() + numberbtn.toString()
    let inputs = currentNumber 
    this.setState({currentNumber: currentNumber, inputs: currentNumber, result: inputs})
  }
```

Comment: I have other functions in my code that uses currentNumber and inputs. So, if I use variables, it won't update the values in the other functions.

Comment: @user3629875: I think you misunderstand the solution. In your code you are updating every state value one of the other and make it depended on the previous state value. Instead you can compute the value upfront and update all state values at the same time.

Comment: In order to understand the issue i am having i have posted a better view of the code in the link below. [https://stackoverflow.com/q/68123742/3629875]. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: @user3629875 Can you share a codesandbox link of your code?