# How to use the setState method to avoid warning massage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this sample program. I am trying to add two numbers and display them in the display section. The code works perfectly the way I want it to work. But the issue is when I run the program, I am getting a warning message saying "Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()".
Now if I change the this.state in my code into this.setState, the program ain't working right. for example, when I click a number, it doesn't show up on the display until the second click. How do I solve this problem using the only setState to avoid the warning message? Thanks.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        display: '',
        inputs: '',
        result: '',
        currentNumber: '',
        previousNumber: '',
        operator: ''
      }
  }

  inputNumber = numberbtn => {
    this.state.currentNumber = this.state.currentNumber.toString() + numberbtn.toString()
    this.state.inputs = this.state.currentNumber 
    this.setState({result: this.state.inputs})
  }

  inputOperator = operatorBtn => {
    if(this.state.currentNumber === '')return

    if(this.state.previousNumber!== ''){
      this.calculateInput()
    }
    this.state.operator = operatorBtn
    this.state.previousNumber = this.state.currentNumber
    this.state.inputs = this.state.previousNumber + operatorBtn
    this.state.result = this.state.inputs
    this.setState({result: this.state.inputs})
    this.setState({display: this.state.result})
    this.setState({result: ''})
    this.state.currentNumber = ''
    this.state.inputs = ''
  }

  calculateInput = () => {
    if(this.state.operator === "+"){
      this.state.result = parseFloat(this.state.previousNumber) + 
                          parseFloat(this.state.currentNumber)
      this.setState({
        result: parseFloat(this.state.previousNumber) + 
                     parseFloat(this.state.currentNumber)
      })
    }
  
    this.state.currentNumber = this.state.result
    this.state.operator = undefined
    this.state.previousNumber = ''
    this.state.inputs = ''
    this.setState({display: ''})
   
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className = "container">
              <div className = "display">
                  <DisplayComponent display={this.state.display}/>
                  <DisplayComponent result={this.state.result}/>
              </div>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(1)}>1</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(2)}>2</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(3)}>3</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputOperator('+')}>+</button>
              <button className = "span" onClick={() =>this.calculateInput('=')}>=</button>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: Don't mutate state in React. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the obvious issue of direct state mutation/manipulation I think you've some unnecessary state and moving parts.

The code/logic could be reduced to a display string (`display`), two operands (`currentNumber` and `previousNumber`), and an operator (`operator`).

The algorithm is simple:

1. Build current number and display strings until operator is entered.
2. Save operator and move current number to previous number.
3. Build current number and display strings until operator or "=" is entered.

   1. If operator is entered, compute result and repeat step 2.
   2. If "=" is entered compute result, clear operator, and update display and current number.

Code:

```js
const DisplayComponent = ({ display }) => <div>{display}</div>;

const initialState = {
  display: "",
  currentNumber: "",
  previousNumber: "",
  operator: ""
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { ...initialState };

  inputNumber = (numberbtn) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      display: prevState.display + numberbtn,
      currentNumber: prevState.currentNumber + numberbtn
    }));
  };

  inputOperator = (operatorBtn) => {
    if (this.state.currentNumber === "") return;

    if (this.state.operator) {
      this.calculateInput();
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      display: prevState.display + operatorBtn,
      currentNumber: "",
      operator: operatorBtn,
      previousNumber: prevState.currentNumber
    }));
  };

  calculateInput = () => {
    const { operator, previousNumber, currentNumber } = this.state;

    if (!(previousNumber && currentNumber)) return;

    let result = Number(previousNumber);
    const v2 = Number(currentNumber);

    switch (operator) {
      case "+":
        result += v2;
        break;

      case "-":
        result -= v2;
        break;

      case "*":
        result *= v2;
        break;

      case "/":
        result /= v2;
        break;

      default:
        throw new Error("invalid opearator");
    }

    this.setState({
      display: result,
      currentNumber: String(result),
      operator: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="display">
          <DisplayComponent display={this.state.display} />
        </div>
        <div>
          {[...Array(10).keys()].map((val) => (
            <button key={val} onClick={() => this.inputNumber(val)}>
              {val}
            </button>
          ))}
          <button onClick={() => this.setState(initialState)}>Clear</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {["+", "-", "*", "/"].map((key) => (
            <button key={key} onClick={() => this.inputOperator(key)}>
              {key}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <button className="span" onClick={() => this.calculateInput("=")}>
          =
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Drew. Just a quick question, I see you use prevState as a parameter but it was not passed as an argument or it wasn't defined. So could you explain to me why you used it and what its purpose is? Thanks!

Comment: @user3629875 Sure, that is an [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) used mostly to reference , and update from, the previous state, as opposed to referencing the state closed over in the callback scope of the render cycle it was attached in. Since we're adding a character to the previous state's strings, a functional state update ensures the updates are kept in order. Here's a demo I use to highlight the difference between the two: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-based-regular-and-functional-state-updates-x2gl7.

Comment: Thank you Drew!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state.inputs = this.state.currentNumber 
this.setState({result: this.state.inputs})
```

it is a nice example to talk about. First you just assign the value at this.state.input and that will occur the error that you talk about. But second one is the right usage. So change all the lines similar to this first line and make them like second line. You have a lot of statements like that and you need to change them all. Hope works.

I edit the code for you, you can check it. Another point to careful about is that you never discharge the value of result so we get the new value after old ones in string. That's why we are setting the result every time empty string at the beginning. You can check it out.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        display: '',
        inputs: '',
        result: '',
        currentNumber: '',
        previousNumber: '',
        operator: ''
      }
  }

  inputNumber = numberbtn => {
    this.setState({currentNumber : this.state.currentNumber.toString() + numberbtn.toString()})
    this.setState({inputs : this.state.currentNumber })
    this.setState({result: this.state.inputs})
  }

  inputOperator = operatorBtn => {
    if(this.state.currentNumber === '')return

    if(this.state.previousNumber!== ''){
      this.calculateInput()
    }

    this.setState({operator :operatorBtn})
    this.setState({previousNumber :this.state.currentNumber})
    this.setState({inputs :this.state.previousNumber + operatorBtn})
    this.setState({result : this.state.inputs})
   
    this.setState({display: this.state.result})
    this.setState({result: ''})
    this.setState({currentNumber: ''})
    this.setState({inputs : ''})
  }

  calculateInput = () => {
    if(this.state.operator === "+"){
    
      
      this.setState({
        result: parseFloat(this.state.previousNumber) + 
                     parseFloat(this.state.currentNumber)
      })
    }
  
    this.setState({currentNumber:this.state.result})
    this.setState({operator :undefined})
    this.setState({previousNumber: ''})
    this.setState({inputs: ''})
    this.setState({display: ''})
   
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div className = "container">
              
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(1)}>1</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(2)}>2</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputNumber(3)}>3</button>
              <button onClick={() =>this.inputOperator('+')}>+</button>
              <button className = "span" onClick={() =>this.calculateInput('=')}>=</button>
              <p>{this.state.result}</p>
          </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App  />,
    document.body
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did but it doesn't work properly. After I changed them to make them like the second line and I click a number, it doesn't show up on the display until the second or third click.

Comment: Try it with your display components please, if you want to DOM render your code every change that you made, you should use setState for it.